# Regex to Find a number after a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm given this value `?({mvp:375760,ms:6})` and I want to be able to only get the number 6 after ms: not the numbers before. I'm fairly new to regex and I don't know how to exclude the ms. I am able to get `ms:6` but not just the value 6 by itself.

I tried `ms.[0-9]` but that gets `'ms:6'`

Comment: I tried ms.[0-9] but that only gets ms:6 I just want 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) `(?<=)` to find a value that follows something else. Here you want a the digit(s) that follow the string `ms:`. That would look like `(?<=ms:)\d+`:

```
import re

s = '?({mvp:375760,ms:6})'

re.search(r'(?<=ms:)\d+', s).group()
# '6'
```

or if there could be more than one:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=ms:)\d', s)
# ['6']
```

Comment: In this case you can also use capture groups:  'ms:(\d+)'  test your regex at regex101.com.